# Mobile schema.org mark ups on Gmail

Tags: google-schemas

Is it possible to user Go-To Actions schema.org mark ups on Gmail on Mobile? Another question would be if the the mark ups we will avoid the promotions tab. The last question is related to deeplinks, if they can be used in the markups.

Comment: This is a very poor question, please be more concrete, post some of your code where you're stuck in and demonstrate your previous research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go-to actions integrate with Gmail and mobile. For mobile, the user will need to be using the Inbox app in order to see the button.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox&hl=en

I believe if the content of your email is promotional, it will end up in the promotions tab.

Yes, deep linking is supported. You can find the documentation and examples at the link below.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/declaring-actions#mobile_deep_linking

I hope this helps player.